# moving file from local user to remote server

Tags: putty, scp

I am connected to a remote server from my laptop and I need to transfer a file to the remote server.

I am using PUTTY to connect to the server and  the scp command to move the file. But I get a nodename or service name not known

**here is what I am putting exactly:**

scp -r D/FolderName/fileToMove userName@remoteServer:DestinationFolder

**I have also tried**

scp -r myComputerUser@myComputerName:D/FolderName/fileToMove
                                                 userName@remoteServer:DestinationFolder

I know the destination path is correct. I am unsure about the source path.

Thanks for the suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i should have researched more before posting. For any one who has a similar question as mine
The link below should help.

http://ksantema.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/use-pscp-to-copy-files-to-network-devices-and-linux-servers/